# MySQL : transaction within a procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures, transactions

The basic structure of my procedure is:

```sql
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    .. Query 1 ..
    .. Query 2 ..
    .. Query 3 ..
  COMMIT;
END;
```

> **MySQL version:** 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1-log

Currently, if 'query 2' fails, result of 'query 1' is committed.

- How can I rollback the transaction if any of the query fails?

Comment: Also note that there is a school of thought with folks who believe transactions should be called outside the scope of a stored procedure and that procedures/functions should be able to be fully inclusive of any calling transaction.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/18817148/632951

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-handler.html

Basically you declare error handler which will call rollback

```
START TRANSACTION;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        EXIT PROCEDURE;
    END;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND ROLLBACK;

Comment: DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

Comment: DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;

Comment: @Priyank Kapasi, great, just to note, I think only last one is really needed.

Comment: DECLARE should only be used after a BEGIN statement

Comment: `EXIT PROCEDURE;` gives me *Syntax error*, is it really needed?. And I had to move the **DECLARE** statement at the beginning of store procedure

Comment: Syntax error near `EXIT PROCEDURE;` on mysql 8.0.23

Answer (score 46):

Just an alternative to the code by  rkosegi,

```
BEGIN

    .. Declare statements ..

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN
          .. set any flags etc  eg. SET @flag = 0; ..
          ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

        .. Query 1 ..
        .. Query 2 ..
        .. Query 3 ..

    COMMIT;
    .. eg. SET @flag = 1; ..

END
```

Answer (score 16):

[*This is just an explanation not addressed in other answers*]

At least in recent versions of MySQL, your first query is not **committed**.

If you query it under the same session you will see the changes, but if you query it from a different session, the changes are not there, they are not **committed**.

### What's going on?

When you open a transaction, and a query inside it fails, the transaction keeps open, it does not **commit** nor **rollback** the changes.

So **BE CAREFUL**, any table/row that was locked with a previous query like `SELECT ... FOR SHARE/UPDATE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or any other locking-query, keeps locked until that session is killed (and executes a rollback), or until a following query commits it explicitly (`COMMIT`) or [implicitly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html), thus making the partial changes **permanent** (which might happen hours later, while the transaction was in a waiting state).

That's why the solution involves declaring handlers to immediately `ROLLBACK` when an error happens.

---

### Extra

Inside the handler you can also re-raise the error using `RESIGNAL`, otherwise the stored procedure executes *"Successfully"*:

```sql
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            RESIGNAL;
        END;

    START TRANSACTION;
        -- .. Query 1 ..
        -- .. Query 2 ..
        -- .. Query 3 ..
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's an example of a transaction that will rollback on error and return the error code.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_CREATE_SERVER_USER`(
    IN P_server_id VARCHAR(100),
    IN P_db_user_pw_creds VARCHAR(32),
    IN p_premium_status_name VARCHAR(100),
    IN P_premium_status_limit INT,
    IN P_user_tag VARCHAR(255),
    IN P_first_name VARCHAR(50),
    IN P_last_name VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE errno INT;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
    GET CURRENT DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 errno = MYSQL_ERRNO;
    SELECT errno AS MYSQL_ERROR;
    ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO server_users(server_id, db_user_pw_creds, premium_status_name, premium_status_limit)
    VALUES(P_server_id, P_db_user_pw_creds, P_premium_status_name, P_premium_status_limit);

    INSERT INTO client_users(user_id, server_id, user_tag, first_name, last_name, lat, lng)
    VALUES(P_server_id, P_server_id, P_user_tag, P_first_name, P_last_name, 0, 0);

    COMMIT WORK;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is assuming that autocommit is set to 0.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) in a [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html). *We cannot use transaction in a [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num int
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose num is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Then, you create `my_proc()` procedure which updates `num` to `5`, then causes error by [SIGNAL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html), then rollbacks with [ROLLBACK statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) in a transaction ([START TRANSACTION and COMMIT statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)) as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE test SET num = 5;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
    ROLLBACK;
  COMMIT;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, calling `my_proc()` gets the error but `num` is not rollbacked to `2` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CALL my_proc();
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
```

Now, you can rollback the transaction in `my_proc()` procedure with [DECLARE ... HANDLER statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html) as shown below. *Be careful, `my_proc()` procedure without a transaction (`START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` statements) doesn't rollback `num` to `2`:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
  END;
  START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE test SET num = 5;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  COMMIT;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Or, you can rollback the transaction in `my_proc()` procedure with this below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN
  DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
  BEGIN  
    SET `_rollback` = 1;
  END;
  START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE test SET num = 5;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  IF `_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
  ELSE
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Then, calling `my_proc()` doesn't get error because the error is handled by `DECLARE ... HANDLER` statement, then `num` is rollbacked to `2` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> CALL my_proc();
...
mysql> SELECT num FROM test;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```