# How can I use transactions in my MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm trying to modify my MySQL stored procedure and make it transactional. The existing stored procedure works fine with no problem but as soon as I make it transactional it does not even allow me to save my changes. I checked MySQL documentation and searched online but I cannot find any problem with my code. It seems to be pretty straight forward but can't figure it out.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE poid INT;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SQLWARNING
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END

START TRANSACTION;

    -- ADD option 5
    INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,5,0);
    SET poid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
    INSERT INTO product_option_value(product_option_id,product_id,option_id,option_value_id,quantity,subtract,price,price_prefix,points,points_prefix,weight,weight_prefix) VALUES(poid,insertedProductID,5,50,0,0,4.99,'+',0,'+',0,'+');

    -- ADD option 12
    INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,12,1);

    -- ADD option 13
    INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,13,0);

COMMIT;

END
```

any idea ?

Comment: Can you post full definition of your stored procedure starting with `CREATE PROCEDURE...`? What is `insertedProductID` and where it's been declared???

Comment: @tohid, I you have forgot ',' between "SQLEXCEPTION SQLWARNING". you should write as follows :  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
 BEGIN
  ROLLBACK;
 END;

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9974325/632951

Answer (score 7):

Two syntax errors:

- You need commas in between the conditions for your exit handler.  Notice the [syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) shows commas.
- You need to terminate the `END` of the exit handler with a semicolon.  The `DECLARE` statement itself (including its BEGIN...END block) is a statement like any other, and need to have a terminator.

So you need this:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks .. I applied the changes you suggested but still getting the same error !

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: I used your code and there's no error (v.5.6.17)... I really don't understand why the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20046066/1326147) was upvoted that much, since he just separated the declares, provides no references and his "explanation" just states the obvious...

Answer (score 5):

Try like this ie, include your `Declare` statement inside the `START TRANSACTION;`. Earlier your `ROLLBACK` was not a part of `TRANSACTION` as you wrote it above the `START TRANSACTION`:-

```
BEGIN

DECLARE poid INT;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING

START TRANSACTION;

BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END

    -- ADD option 5
    INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,5,0);
    SET poid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
    INSERT INTO product_option_value(product_option_id,product_id,option_id,option_value_id,quantity,subtract,price,price_prefix,points,points_prefix,weight,weight_prefix) VALUES(poid,insertedProductID,5,50,0,0,4.99,'+',0,'+',0,'+');

    -- ADD option 12
    INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,12,1);

    -- ADD option 13
    INSERT INTO product_option(product_id,option_id,required) VALUES(insertedProductID,13,0);

COMMIT;

END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Still get the following error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE poid INT;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SQLWARNING
BEGIN
    RO' at line 11

Comment: It seems the problem is that after `START TRANSACTION` MySQL does not expect a `DECLARE`...

Comment: You can't use `DECLARE` after using something else written after `BEGIN`

Answer (score -1):

Put your `DECLARE`s after the first `BEGIN` and it should work.

If you use BEGIN and END to group multiple statements, you normally also need to declare an alternate DELIMITER at the top and replace the ; after the last END with it.