# How to rollback all statements inside a MySQL Transaction?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, rollback

I need to update a specific column of a table (`bigtable`) containing ids of another table (FK constraint to `oldsmalltable`) to point to ids on another table (FK constraint to `newsmalltable`). Basically this is what I am doing:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE updatebigtable ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

    START TRANSACTION;
        ALTER TABLE bigtable DROP FOREIGN KEY bigtable_ibfk_1,
            MODIFY smalltable_id SMALLINT ;
        UPDATE bigtable SET smalltable_id=CASE smalltable_id
                WHEN 1 THEN 1592
                WHEN 2 THEN 1593
                WHEN 3 THEN 1602
                ...
                ELSE 0
            END;
        ALTER TABLE bigtable ADD CONSTRAINT bigtable_ibfk_1
            FOREIGN KEY(smalltable_id) REFERENCES newsmalltable(id);
    COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL updatebigtable();
DROP PROCEDURE updatebigtable;
```

I need to ensure that if by some reason the new Foreign Key constraint fails (e.g. with columns with different types, the error would occur on the last `alter table` statement), the `UPDATE` and the first `ALTER TABLE` should be rolled back as well, i.e. they should remain as they were initially.

According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), by using `START TRANSACTION` the autocommit mode is disabled for that transaction, which will **not** allow:

> that as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent.

I only found this question as minimally related to mine:

[How can I use transactions in my MySQL stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817148/how-can-i-use-transactions-in-my-mysql-stored-procedure)

If that error I mentioned occurs inside the transaction, the previous statements were already executed and the updates were "permanently done on disk"...

I also tried to place `SET autocommit=0;` before creating the procedure but the behavior is still the same... Am I missing something? Or is this the expected behavior of a MySQL transaction rollback?

If it makes any difference, I am using MySQL v.5.6.17.

Comment: Check: [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE` statements always cause an implicit commit ([section 13.3.3 from MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html), thanks [wchiquito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020759/how-to-rollback-all-statements-inside-a-mysql-transaction/34022905#comment55796412_34020759)), which means that even if they're inside a `START TRANSACTION;` ... `COMMIT;` block, there will be as many commits as the number of alters done inside that block.

Locking the table is not an option as well since ([from problems with `ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table-problems.html)):

> If you use `ALTER TABLE` on a transactional table or if you are using Windows, `ALTER TABLE` unlocks the table if you had done a `LOCK TABLE` on it. This is done because InnoDB and these operating systems cannot drop a table that is in use.

The only option left for avoiding unwanted reads/writes while the alter and update statements are being executed is emulating all the steps of an `ALTER TABLE`:

> 1. Create a new table named A-xxx with the requested structural changes.
> 2. Copy all rows from the original table to A-xxx.
> 3. Rename the original table to B-xxx.
> 4. Rename A-xxx to your original table name.
> 5. Delete B-xxx.

This way the updates can be done in the new table (after step 2) and the only time the `bigtable` is unavailable is while doing step 3 and 4 (renaming).

Answer (score -2):

Use a TRY CATCH block
BEGIN TRAN before BEGIN TRY and ROLLBACK TRAN inside CATCH block

Comment: [try-catch statement](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_try_catch.html) -> [common-schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html)?.

Comment: MySQL, not MS SQL.