# MariaDB/MySQL: Rollback not working in procedure

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb

I am trying to create a procedure that contains a transaction that has a rollback:

```
create or replace procedure move_animals(in diernaam varchar(25)) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
            START TRANSACTION;

        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
        end;
        insert into moved_animals(naam)
            values(diernaam);   
        delete from animals 
            where naam in (diernaam);
        COMMIT;
    end;
    
call move_animals("giraf");
```

However, when I am doing an insert on table `moved_animals` that isn't possible due to unique constraints it's still deleting that record from `animal`. I would like to then rollback and undo the delete. What am I missing here?

Comment: This code makes no sense. When an exception happens you start a transaction?

Comment: I fixed the indentation to match the code structure. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: @Barmar, I understand better now yes, thank you! I was going off of this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987510/5790778

Comment: So you just copied it wrong, since that answer is basically the same as my answer here. You need to understand the answer instead of just copy/pasting blindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `START TRANSACTION` and `ROLLBACK` in the wrong places. You should roll back in the exception handler, and start the transaction in the main body of the procedure.

```
create or replace procedure move_animals(in diernaam varchar(25)) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
        ROLLBACK;

    START TRANSACTION;
    insert into moved_animals(naam)
        values(diernaam);   
    delete from animals 
        where naam in (diernaam);
    COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much, that makes a lot more sense.